# Broken logic causing if statement not to work

Tags: java, swing, math, if-statement

Im trying to complete this game.  The following code is where im at right now.  You need to guess a number between 1 and 100.  lets say the number is 50 and you first guess 40.  If your next guess is 39 it should tell you that you are getting colder.  I have some if statements near the bottom that are not performing what the way they need to.  The only way it tells you that you are getting colder is if you guess 100 over what the numberToGuess is.  I dont know whats wrong.

If you run the code I have modified it to make it easier to troubleshoot.  At the bottom you will be given the correct answer.  TO the right of that is the currentDistance

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import helpers.*;

public class GuessGame extends JPanel{  
    private static int GUESS_MAX = 100;
    private static int GUESS_MIN = 0;
    private static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
    private static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 325;
    private int lastDistance;       
    private int currentDistance;
    private int guessCount = 0;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int numberToGuess = 0;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton tryButton;
    private JButton newGameButton;
    private ExitButton exitButton;
    private JLabel guessLabel;
    private JTextField guessField;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel countLabel;
    private JLabel alertLabel;
    private JPanel panel;   

    public GuessGame(){ 
        numberToGuess = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Number Guessing Game");     
        mainFrame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);          
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);      
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10,10);           
        tryButton = new JButton("Try the number");
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        exitButton = new ExitButton();
        headerLabel = new JLabel("<html>I have a whole number between 1 and 100,<br>can you guess the number?</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        guessLabel = new JLabel("Enter a guess:");
        guessField = new JTextField(5);
        countLabel = new JLabel("# of guesses: 0");
        tryButton = new JButton("Try the number");      
        alertLabel = new JLabel("Awaiting Input");
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        exitButton = new ExitButton();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(headerLabel, c);      
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 1;
        panel.add(guessLabel, c);       
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy= 1;
        panel.add(guessField, c);       
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(countLabel, c);       
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 3;     
        panel.add(tryButton, c);        
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 4;
        panel.add(alertLabel, c);       
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy= 5;
        panel.add(newGameButton, c);        
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy= 5;
        panel.add(exitButton, c);

        newGameButton.setMnemonic('N');
        NewGameButtonHandler nghandler = new NewGameButtonHandler();
        newGameButton.addActionListener(nghandler);
        tryButton.setMnemonic('T');
        TryButtonHandler tryhandler = new TryButtonHandler();
        tryButton.addActionListener(tryhandler);        
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    class NewGameButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        numberToGuess = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
        countLabel.setText("# of guesses: 0");
        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        alertLabel.setText("Awaiting Input");
        guessField.setText("");
        guessCount = 0;
        tryButton.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    class TryButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        int lastDist = lastDistance;        

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {       
            int guess;
            boolean correct = false;                
            String instring = guessField.getText();

            if (guessCount == 0)
            {
                lastDistance = GUESS_MAX;
            }           
            guess = Integer.parseInt(instring); 

            if(guess >= GUESS_MIN && guess <= GUESS_MAX)
            {                               
                {
                    guessCount= guessCount + 1;             
                    countLabel.setText("# of guesses: " + guessCount);
                }
                if (guess > numberToGuess)
                {
                    alertLabel.setText("Too high. ");
                }
                else if (guess < numberToGuess)
                {
                    alertLabel.setText("Too low. ");
                }
                else
                {
                    alertLabel.setText("Correct!");
                    correct = true;
                    alertLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    tryButton.setVisible(false);
                }
            }               
            if (correct == false)
            {                   
                    currentDistance = Math.abs((guess - numberToGuess));

                    if (currentDistance <= lastDist && guessCount !=1)
                    {
                        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
                        alertLabel.setText(alertLabel.getText() + " Getting warmer");
                    }
                    else if(currentDistance >= lastDist && guessCount !=1)
                    {
                        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                        alertLabel.setText(alertLabel.getText() + " Getting colder");
                    }               
            }   

            lastDist = currentDistance;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuessGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do any debugging yourself? If so, what did you discover?

Comment: Aside: `if (correct == false)` <- bad practice .. `if (!correct)` <- good practice

Comment: I'm suspicious of `if (correct == false)` because it doesn't have `{` and `}` following it. This means only the next statement will be in the if block, and not the `if (currentDistance <= lastDistance)` bit. Is that OK? From your indentation, it seems like you expect otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I sloved you problem at least it works now but there could Always be a bug somewhere.
So I basically rewrote your try button handler so it works now. I hope that you will be able to find the changes and understand them and if not you can Always ask.

The changes I made are enclosed between `//Me start` and `//Me end`.

I also had to edit some things to make the errors go away but those changes are all marked as TODO as you probably have the corresponding classes in you project.

```
package Week5;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
//import helpers.*;TODO this import was no found but it is probably in your project

public class GuessGame extends JPanel{

private static int GUESS_MAX = 100;
private static int GUESS_MIN = 0;
private static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
private static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 325;
private Random random = new Random();
private int numberToGuess = 0;
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JButton tryButton;
private JButton newGameButton;
private ExitButton exitButton;
private JLabel guessLabel;
private JTextField guessField;
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel countLabel;
private JLabel alertLabel;
private JPanel panel;

private JLabel cheat;
private JLabel cheat2;

public GuessGame(){ 
numberToGuess = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
mainFrame = new JFrame("Number Guessing Game");     
mainFrame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);          
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);      
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10,10);       

tryButton = new JButton("Try the number");
newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
exitButton = new ExitButton();
headerLabel = new JLabel("<html>I have a whole number between 1 and 100,<br>can you guess the   number?</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
guessLabel = new JLabel("Enter a guess:");
guessField = new JTextField(5);
countLabel = new JLabel("# of guesses: 0");
tryButton = new JButton("Try the number");      
alertLabel = new JLabel("Awaiting Input");
newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
exitButton = new ExitButton();

cheat = new JLabel(String.valueOf(numberToGuess));
cheat2 = new JLabel("no value");

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 0;
c.gridwidth = 2;
panel.add(headerLabel, c);      
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 1;
panel.add(guessLabel, c);       
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy= 1;
panel.add(guessField, c);       
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 2;
c.gridwidth = 2;
panel.add(countLabel, c);       
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 3;     
panel.add(tryButton, c);        
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 4;
panel.add(alertLabel, c);       
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy= 5;
panel.add(newGameButton, c);        
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy= 5;
panel.add(exitButton, c);   
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 6;
panel.add(cheat, c);
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 6;
panel.add(cheat2, c);

newGameButton.setMnemonic('N');
NewGameButtonHandler nghandler = new NewGameButtonHandler();
newGameButton.addActionListener(nghandler);
tryButton.setMnemonic('T');
TryButtonHandler tryhandler = new TryButtonHandler();
tryButton.addActionListener(tryhandler);

mainFrame.setVisible(true);



}

//Me start - TODO this class was missing but you probably have it so just remove this.
class ExitButton extends JButton{   
}
//Me end

class NewGameButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
numberToGuess = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
countLabel.setText("# of guesses: 0");
alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
alertLabel.setText("Awaiting Input");
guessField.setText("");
cheat.setText(String.valueOf(numberToGuess));
//Me start
guessCount = 0;
lastDist = 0;
//Me end
}
}

//Me start
static int guessCount = 0;
static int lastDist = 0;
class TryButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int guess;
    try{
        guess = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        alertLabel.setText("That is not a number!");
        return;
    }
    if(guess < GUESS_MIN || guess > GUESS_MAX){
        alertLabel.setText("That number is out of range!");
        lastDist = distance(guess);
        guessCount++;
        return;
    }
    if(guessCount == 0){
        if(guess > numberToGuess){
            alertLabel.setText("Too high. ");
        }else if(guess < numberToGuess){
            alertLabel.setText("Too low. ");
        }
        lastDist = distance(guess);
        guessCount++;
        return;
    }
    if(guess == numberToGuess){
        alertLabel.setText("Correct!");
        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        return;
    }
    int dist = distance(guess);
    if(dist < lastDist){
        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        alertLabel.setText(" Getting warmer");
    }else if(dist > lastDist){
        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        alertLabel.setText("Getting colder");
    }else{
        alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        alertLabel.setText("Why did you enter the same number?");
    }
    lastDist = dist;
    cheat2.setText(String.valueOf(guess));
    guessCount++;
}

private int distance(int guess){
    return numberToGuess - guess < 0 ? guess - numberToGuess : numberToGuess - guess;
}
}
//Me end

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GuessGame();
}
}
```

I hope this works :).

P.S. By the way distance is a method I added inside the button handler.

Comment: Once I realized it was a problem with state variables I went through and finished it up.  I just updated my post and now it runs error free.  I'm going to have to take this down later at the cost of my reputation because I don't want to give cheaters a good grade :-)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: why did you add the @Override to the button handler

Comment: Oh that was just automatically added by eclipse it doesn't really matter. Glad you solved it :). And the @Override is added because the method overrides an super type method. But it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that `if (correct == false)` should probably be followed by brackets, since you only want to 
display the Getting Warmer/Colder message if the current guess is wrong.

```
     if (correct == false) {
        currentDistance = Math.abs((guess - numberToGuess));
        if (currentDistance <= lastDistance)
        {
            alertLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
            alertLabel.setText(" Getting warmer");

            cheat2.setText(String.valueOf(currentDistance));
        }
        else
        {
            alertLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            alertLabel.setText("Getting colder");
            cheat2.setText(String.valueOf(currentDistance));
        }
        lastDistance = currentDistance;
    }
```

In addition, it looks like you initialize some variable each time a guess is made :

```
    int guessCount = 0;

    if (guessCount == 0)
    {
        lastDistance = GUESS_MAX;
    }
```

This initialization should be done only when a name game begins.